# Swift CIfilter select from a collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-image, ciimage

I am working on a app which will give the user the possibility to select a photo apply a filter and save it. 
Basically is a copy of the instagram app camera where the user select a photo from library, apply a filter and then post it.

The app is working fine, my only issue is that when loading the collectionView with the filtered images the process is kind of slow.
I've read around a bit (I am new to swift and this is the first time I ever worked with core image) and I have tried to apply all the pieces of advise I've learnt.
However I believe the app is still running slow.

So here' what I have done.

I have created a model with the filters:

```
public protocol Filter {
 // reference to the core image filter
var filter: CIFilter { get }
 // output of the filter.
var outputImage: CIImage? { get }
}

 // common to all filters.
 extension Filter {
   public var outputImage: CIImage? { return self.filter.outputImage }
}

//Bloom
public class Bloom: Filter {

public let filter: CIFilter

public init(inputImage: CIImage, inputRadius: CGFloat = 10.0, 
 inputIntensity: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    let parameters:[String : Any] = [
        "inputImage":inputImage,
        "inputRadius":inputRadius,
        "inputIntensity":inputIntensity        ]
    guard let filter = CIFilter(name:"CIBloom", withInputParameters: parameters) else { fatalError() }
    self.filter = filter
  }
}


// Box Blur
public class BoxBlur: Filter {

public let filter: CIFilter

public init(inputImage: CIImage, inputRadius: CGFloat = 10.0) {
    let parameters:[String : Any] = [
        "inputImage":inputImage,
        "inputRadius":inputRadius        ]
    guard let filter = CIFilter(name:"CIBoxBlur", withInputParameters: parameters) else { fatalError() }
    self.filter = filter
  }
}
...........
```

and so on for all the filters I need.

Than I have created a class to create an UIImage array with all the filtered images:

```
class filteredImages {
static var filterToApply: Filter!
static var filterNames = [
    "Original","Sepia","Poster",....
]

static var filteredImages = [UIImage]()
static var filteredImage: UIImage!

static func createImageArray(inputImage: CIImage, onSuccess: @escaping () -> () ) {
    filteredImages.removeAll()
    for filter in filterNames {
        switch filter {
        case "Original":
            filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage:inputImage)
            filteredImages.append(filteredImage)
        case "Sepia":
            filterToApply = SepiaTone(inputImage: inputImage, inputIntensity: 0.8)
            filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: filterToApply.outputImage!)
            filteredImages.append(filteredImage)
............
      }
      onSuccess()
     }
   }
}
```

And finally in my controller:

```
var filteredImagesArray = [UIImage]()
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: (originalImage.image?.resized(toWidth: 120))!)!
    filteredImages.createImageArray(inputImage: inputImage) {
        self.filteredImagesArray = filteredImages.filteredImages
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilterCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterCell

        cell.filteredImage.image = filteredImagesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.filterName.text = filteredImages.filterNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.7
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    return cell
}
```

I have also an extension to reduce the "original" image:

```
extension UIImage {
func resized(toWidth width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(ceil(width/size.width * size.height)))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can make it faster?
Am I missing something?

Thank you.

-----------UPDATE AS PER Ladislav REQUEST

Here's the code that I use to get images from the library:

```
  enum Section: Int {
    case allPhotos = 0
    case smartAlbums
    case userCollections

    static let count = 3
}
var allPhotos: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
var allPhotosFromAlbum = PHFetchResult<PHAsset>()
var smartAlbums: [PHAssetCollection] = []
var userCollections: PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection>!
let subtypes:[PHAssetCollectionSubtype] = [
    .smartAlbumFavorites,
    .smartAlbumPanoramas,
    .smartAlbumScreenshots,
    .smartAlbumSelfPortraits,
    .smartAlbumVideos,
    .smartAlbumRecentlyAdded,
    .smartAlbumSelfPortraits
]
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Create a PHFetchResult object for each section in the table view.
    let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "estimatedAssetCount > 0")
    options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "localizedTitle", ascending: false)]
    smartAlbums = fetchSmartCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtypes: subtypes)
    userCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .albumRegular, options: options)
}
```

here's the function i use to get PHAssetCollection with Subtypes:

```
private func fetchSmartCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType, subtypes: [PHAssetCollectionSubtype]) -> [PHAssetCollection] {
    var collections:[PHAssetCollection] = []
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.includeHiddenAssets = false

    for subtype in subtypes {
        if let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: with, subtype: subtype, options: options).firstObject, collection.photosCount > 0 {
            collections.append(collection)
        }
    }

    return collections
}
```

I display the results in a tableView and then upon selection i pass all the images in the album to another controller.

Here's the code of the controller (let's call it mMainVC) where i actually display the images to select:

```
fileprivate let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
if fetchResult == nil {
        let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
    }
}
```

and here the function to get the image from the fetchResult:

```
func selectImageFromAssetAtIndex(index: Int) {
    let asset = fetchResult.object(at: index)
    let size = scrollViewImage.frame.size.width

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: size, height: size), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: { (image, info) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.displayImageInScrollView(image: image!)
        }
    })
}
```

---------------------SCREENSHOT AND VIDEO

[image]
[image]

here's the link for the video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6U8olIA_ZS8U0tpN0hKOWdrVm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you getting photos from Camera roll?

Comment: @Ladislav yes I am getting the photo from the photo Library... i will implement later the possibility to shot a photo and then apply the filter

Comment: Can you add the snippet of code how you are currently getting the images from PhotoKit...?

Comment: @Ladislav sure i'll update my question..

Comment: @Ladislav I have added the code

Comment: So as I can see you have main image in the app and like instagram you have filters down below in a horizontal collection view where user can scroll left and right to choose a given filter...

Comment: @Ladislav exactly... it is basically a copy of that instagram part...same layout and same functionality... with different filters.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that you are doing is good I think, the only problem is that

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: (originalImage.image?.resized(toWidth: 120))!)!
    filteredImages.createImageArray(inputImage: inputImage) {
        self.filteredImagesArray = filteredImages.filteredImages
    }
}
```

`createImageArray` is called on the main thread and that is why your app freezes.

I would add a state `loading` with `activityIndicator` to each `collectionView` `cell` and cells would be in `loading` state until you get result back from the `createImageArray` call, then you would populate cells with filtered images, something like:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {[weak self] in
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: (originalImage.image?.resized(toWidth: 120))!)!
        filteredImages.createImageArray(inputImage: inputImage) {
            self.filteredImagesArray = filteredImages.filteredImages
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems

                collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So at the point where you are reloading visible items `self.filteredImagesArray` will be set and you will be able to disable `loading` state and show the images from the `filteredImagesArray`

Comment: Thank you for the answer... my issue is that when the collectionview scrolls at a certain point will run slow... what you have suggested might help in this? sorry but seen that i'm so new to swift i 'm not sure i understand it 100%... Should I apply the loading state in the cellForItemAt?

Comment: When collection view is loaded and you have already filtered all the images that you store into `self.filteredImagesArray` it should be very fast from then on...

Comment: Please also post maybe a screenshot or two of the app, maybe I am missing something here...

Comment: Hard to say what is up...send me a message on Twitter @ladislavklinc and maybe I can give you some more help directly...